# Helpful spam flags should not be counted to the per site daily flag limit

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

During spam attacks we, as a community, are happily [flagging posts as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035). On most sites spam posts are not long-lived. However on sites with low traffic it can take a while before spam posts reach their 6 required flags, more often than not by community members that call out for help in chatrooms.

The number of flags a day ([10 but raising with your rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/increase-the-number-of-daily-spam-flags-with-reputation)) per site can be fully consumed by just spam flags and after that you're out of the game.

I rather see that the spam-flags raised are not counted towards the daily-site-limit if, and only if, the post is flagged by 5 other community members as spam. The spam-flag limit should be a network-wide-limit, so you could use flags from other sites associated with your account for spam flags, and topped at the maxiumnumber of flags per day, based on your reputation with a maxium of 100 flags.

I've seen and read:
[Better tools to handle spam on low traffic sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193353/better-tools-to-handle-spam-on-low-traffic-sites) is without an answer but a lengthy comment discussion.

[Slightly related but out-of-scope of my request: Stronger spam flags for trusted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139633/stronger-spam-flags-for-trusted-users)

Comment: Just to play devils advocate (as I think this is a good idea), a group of 6 users could potentially delete as spam all the content on a site

Comment: Also, to let you know you get more flags per day by getting 10 (helpful - declined) flags. Right now I'm capped at 100 on SO, but don't have anywhere near the amount of rep that would take.

Comment: Yes, spam is bad, yes, flagging spam is great, but noone but the moderators should have unlimited flags.

Comment: @rene: There already is a rep component to the number of flags you have.

Comment: @hichris123 I've got 10 flags on Magento. 10 is way too little if the Baba guy decides to relocate again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, I see no need to separate flags into spam and regular flags, even for something as heinous as spam.

All you need is a set of sockpuppets or voting ring with flagging privileges to make *anything* disappear from the site, simply by flagging it as spam. With additional spam flags, you can do a lot of damage this way.

Note that your flag allowance [scales with reputation and your flagging ratio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890), up to *100 flags per day*.

I'd be pretty exhausted if I used all my 100 flags in a day on a spammer, I'd be happy for someone else to take over for a while by that time.

What we need then, is *more people* helping out fight spam. [Better protection and tools are under way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/the-review-system-suggested-something-was-probably-spam-what-should-i-do-when-i).

Comment: Can the flag  allowance _at least_ be network-wide?

Comment: @JanDvorak: When a spammer goes network-wide, does it really go 10+ posts per site?

Comment: When a spammer decides to focus on one site (say, because the local community doesn't remove spam fast enough), 10 flags don't suffice. This has already happened more than once to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I am weary of going into a site I don't know the culture of; spam may be obvious, but I would rather see some caution before letting in 'neighbours' into the community with spam flags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You'd be suprised, I've used a *lot* of spam flags on some sites.

Comment: I've run out of flags on spam _only_ recently on [magento.se]. By flagging six hours worth of spam. The rest got dumped to the tavern where Bart flagged away the other. When the sports spam was hot, I've been running out of flags _constantly_.

Comment: @JanDvorak: So you were able to cope, as a community? Now that you have accumulated helpful flags on Magento, you can battle such an attack for 7 or 8 hours next time round, right?

Comment: No. We were not able to cope. The only reason the spam went away so fast was that a CM was sitting in the tavern at that time (or do I misremember, and the spam did not go away fast?)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I am trying to gauge if there is a real problem here that only more spam flags (or an 'association bonus' for spam flags on neighbour sites) can solve.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Wasn't the problem then that there were not enough people coming in to fight the spam? If you had more spam flags, you would still have been the only one fighting the good fight. Do you know for a fact others did not come in to help because they had run out of flags?

Comment: @MartijnPieters just install my userscript and wait for the next peak. Or sit in the tavern and watch me run out of flags when the peak comes.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I have the User Script installed. I just don't always have the time to watch out for a peak or sit in the tavern.

Comment: Frankly, the preferred solution would be a community moderator running my script on his computer

Comment: The userscript supports desktop notifications. If you can't clear them, you can still accumulate them to clear them later.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I understand that there are persistent annoying spammers, and that we need more attention to keep those lowlifes out. I am just not seeing how more spam flags are going to solve that problem. Just like the close review queue, we need more *people* on the job, or tools to keep the spam out earlier.

Comment: I guess I won't be given the permission to singlehandedly delete spam anywhere on the network? :-)

Comment: But I agree... more people are needed

Comment: I should point out that I thought for a while that the use of a ring of sock puppets to spam-flag something into oblivion was a purely theoretical exploit. Then we had two separate people do this last year, and others try over the last couple of months. So it is possible, although really rare. Needless to say, we come down like a ton of bricks on anyone we find doing this.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I am hoping that the new learning-based spam protection system will eventually reduce the need for as many people to be summoned to non-SO sites to combat this. Tim talks about this in terms of edits here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/the-review-system-suggested-something-was-probably-spam-what-should-i-do-when-i , but as we destroy spammers on one site, the entire network should start picking up and automatically blocking their activity. That should start defending the smaller sites from outbreaks like the streaming TV spam. Initial reports sound promising.

Comment: @BradLarson do you mean _my_ learning spam-catcher will have nothing to do? That's great :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you edit your first line (because that is no longer true in the current version of the question) I'm happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @rene: your requests still talks about spam flags not counting against your flag limit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters We are probably lost in translation because in my version I read: *The spam-flag limit should be a network-wide-limit, so you could use flags from other sites associated with your account for spam flags, and topped at the maxiumnumber of flags per day, based on your reputation with a maxium of 100 flags.* That would defeat your first sentence I guess. I'm okay that you're against giving out more flags as is dicussed with JanDvorak and I agree that having more people raising spam-flags is the real solution.

Comment: @rene: I see; you are going with the 'network wide' idea there. Updated to reflect the discussion  some more.

Comment: Your spam-catcher is not going to sit idle @JanDvorak