# Let's meet spam waves with flag waves!

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

I've been helping in the Great Ask Ubuntu Spam War recently, and one thing I've noticed is that 10-20 flags usually isn't enough during a wave. It feels, quite frankly, terrible to have to sit out during a spam wave.

Therefore, I propose the following: If there is currently a spam wave (i.e. posts flagged out of existence > *x*) , give users *x * n* more flags than usual.

The implementation details are arbitrary and up to the SE people, of course. I'm planning on fleshing this out more in the future, but I'm just throwing this out there. Maybe someone has the ultimate formula.

Comment: Related, but nowhere near a dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216825/helpful-spam-flags-should-not-be-counted-to-the-per-site-daily-flag-limit

Comment: how about "if you flag a post that was created/edited in the last X hour(s) as spam, you get your flag back if it gets accepted"?

Comment: @ajax333221 That would help a lot, and I think that already happens for high rep users.

Comment: There is the potential for abuse in this, though. Say someone gets enough sock puppets together to start coordinating spam flags. They could direct this group of puppets to spam flag and destroy legitimate posts, then because this would be much higher spam volume than normal, they'd get more spam flags to keep doing this. They could destroy a lot of content very quickly with no cap on the flags. Also, if they were fast enough about it, or timed it right, no moderator would be made aware until well after a lot of damage had been done. A cap at least limits them.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS It does not. However, by virtue of high rep and good flagging histories, they generally have access to many more flags than the average user.

Comment: @Brad Yes, I'm worried about that part. There has to be a way to do it, though, still limiting the amount of abuse that happens. Maybe do something like only put the extra-flag-giver to users with >*x* rep on at least *x* sites? I'm just thinking out loud here, of course.